# Use of app has been restricted

Tags: facebook-apps, restrictions

I have created an App, which works fine for me (presumably because I am the developer), but when anyone else tries to load it, they get this error -

> Use of app "UK News from Dyne Drewett" has been restricted

I have looked in the Help Centre at this FAQ - http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=155308851202619 - but clicking on the 'Appeal Page' link just takes me to a page that says 'Currently, none of your apps are restricted.'

I can find no information in the App Settings, nor see any helpful hints when trying to view the app as another person that tells me what may be causing this.

Does anybody have any ideas on what I can look at to fix this problem?

App location - http://apps.facebook.com/dyne_drewett_news/ (no SSL yet, so will not work if you have security mode enabled). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go in the APP Dashboard under Advanced option there are the restriction settings, or go Insights under API->Attivity and Error to view restriction

Comment: Thanks for your reply - under 'Settings -> Advanced -> Restrictions', I have in the Uk and over 13, both requirements the users that have tested meet. And under 'API -> Activity and Errors' there are no errors reported at all. Any other suggestions would be apprciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

That message means the app has been restricted by the developer (i.e you) and can't be seen by users in certain demographics.

This is usually done by the API via the ['restrictions' connection of the Application object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/#restrictions), or via the Restrictions setting in the app dashboard, under the 'advanced' tab

[image]

If you're sure you haven't set such restrictions, and your users are definitely logged in when they try to access the app, is there any chance at all you've forgotten to disable Sandbox mode?

[image]

There's also a slightly different, though similar, message if the users are using HTTPS and you've forgotten to enter the HTTPS settings or they're using HTTP and you've only put in HTTPS settings but i think that error message is clearer about why the app can't be accessed

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sandbox is off, and both HTTP and HTTPS are set (although I don't have a certificate quite yet). I think I have found what the problem is though - I restricted the App to the UK, as it is really only relevant here, and apparently Facebook thinks that people are not in the UK when they clearly are - removing that restriction allows the App to work. I'm not sure exactly what Facebook checks for location, but both the timezone and language are set correctly on my computer, and any option I can find on Facebook says UK. Thanks for you time.

Comment: Are you actually in the UK? (with an ISP that is based in the UK?) - the location detection is mostly IP based as far as I know

Comment: I certainly am. ISP is Opel (TalkTalk Business), which is a UK.